# How to resolve the permission errors for MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, doctrine-orm, symfony4, php-7.2

I am trying to work on this project. https://github.com/thiagogomesverissimo/symfony_traditional_login
Following the instructions. But when I was executing

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Then I get the following errors:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access 
denied for user 'master'@'localhost' (using password: YES)                               

In PDOConnection.php line 50:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 
'master'@'localhost'(using 
password: YES)                                                                

In PDOConnection.php line 46:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'master'@'localhost' 
(using password: YES)
```

I did try to edit the mysql url in the env file like below:

https://github.com/thiagogomesverissimo/symfony_traditional_login/blob/master/.env.dist

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://db_username:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_mydbname
```

Another try was:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost/mydbname
```

I am just replacing the username, password, and mydbname with my information. But still getting the same errors. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to mention the env: php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --env=prod

Comment: I just tried your suggestion like this php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --env=prod, but still the same errors, unfortunately.